# Adding values to an undefined index array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database-connection

I'm working on learning php by creating a webpage completely based on php and dynamic to the content of a database. In the code snippet below, I query the amount of navigation links in the mainMenu table and return the link title and url to their respective arrays. However, the code is broken and the webpage doesn't load. I'm almost 100% certain it is the way I am declaring the arrays, or the way I am trying to pass the data from the database to the array but after some research I can't figure it out.

```
include('config.php');

$urls = array();
$navs = array();
$num = 1;

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    die("Connection failed");
}
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mainMenu")) {
    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    /* close result set */
    //$result->close();
}

while ($num <= $row_cnt) {
    $sqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if ($sqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    //Site Title
    $sql = "SELECT title,url FROM mainMenu WHERE navID=" . $num;
    $result = $sqli->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $navs[$num] = $row["title"];
        $urls[$num] = $row["url"];
    }
    $sqli->close();
    $num++;
}
```

Comment: arrays aren't objects, you don't use `new` to instantiate them: simply `$urls = array();`

Comment: 1) Make a connection to the database at the top of the code and use it until you are done with it. 2) $row_cnt is undefined. So, the while loop will never be used because 1 > undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that snippet of code. Also, I saw `new` on a post elsewhere but obviously doesn't apply.

Comment: You create `$sqli` but then check `$conn->connect_error`. That should be `$sqli->connect_error`

Comment: When your code is broken and the page won't load, check your logs! Typically the apache `error.log` file. Also you can turn on `error_reporting` to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing an answer that was posted and then deleted, this seemed to be the solution.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$urls = array(); // you shouldn't do "new array()", this is javascript
$navs = array();
$num = 1;
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    die("Connection failed");
}
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mainMenu")) {
    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    /* close result set */
    //$result->close();
}
while ($num <= $row_cnt) {
    //Site Title
    $sql = "SELECT title,url FROM mainMenu WHERE navID=" . $num;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if(!isset($navs[$num])) { $navs[$num] = array(); } // do this to define the index before using it
        if(!isset($urls[$num])) { $urls[$num] = array(); }
        $navs[$num] = $row["title"];
        $urls[$num] = $row["url"];
    }
    $num++;
}


$conn->close();
define('urlArray', $urls);
printf($urls);
?>
```